# Presigned GET url returning a 403

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to use `aws-sdk` to get a temporary private URL for a file in a bucket, but the URL being generated gives me a 403 in the browser. Here's the code:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
bucket = s3.bucket('media.coolstuff.com')
obj = bucket.object('01.mp4')
obj.presigned_url(:get, expires_in: 3600, virtual_host: true)
```

Returns:

```
=> "http://media.coolstuff.com:80/01.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ75FYMC7AZWUI52A%2F20151024%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20151024T224953Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=3bb646db5a50848bdc227066c5ecc70ad249dd404b63b8b799363aa360f18ef6"
```

In the browser, this URL leads to a 403:

```
403 Forbidden
Code: AccessDenied
Message: Access Denied
```

The credentials used belong to a user who is in a group that has the `AmazonS3FullAccess` permission.

How can I generate a presigned url for an object that will be accessible in a web browser?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm able to list the bucket and download an image, but when I pre-sign a URL and try to access that, I get a 403.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working for me, please note the `us-east-1`

```
S3_URL_EXPIRY = 3600 * 24 * 2
S3_SIGNED_URL_REGION = 'us-east-1'.freeze
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: S3_SIGNED_URL_REGION, access_key_id: *access_key_id*, secret_access_key: *secret_access_key*)
obj = s3.bucket('media.coolstuff.com').object('01.mp4')
obj.presigned_url(:get, expires_in: S3_URL_EXPIRY, virtual_host: true)
```

Where `*access_key_id*` & `*secret_access_key*` are your access_key_id & secret_access_key respectively.